# SQLite exception in LIKE query

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got search query "aa bb" and also there is "aa bb cc" row in table. So my sql query should return that row. This is how I do:

```
select * from company
   where 
      (ASCII_NAME like %'aa'% 
      and ASCII_NAME like %'bb'%) 
   and CITY_ID=0 and parent=-1;
```

But my log says:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: select * from company where (ASCII_NAME like
>   %'aa'% and ASCII_NAME like %'bb'%) and
>   CITY_ID=0 and parent=-1

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong

```
select * from company
   where 
      (ASCII_NAME like '%aa%' 
      and ASCII_NAME like '%bb%') 
   and CITY_ID=0 and parent=-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Include % sign in single quotes.
Like:

```
select emp_name from employee where emp_name like '%s%';
```